# Facebook Graph API: Get user location

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get facebook user location with this code but it's not working:

```
        $user_fbid  = $fbuser;
        $user_email = $user_profile["email"];
        $user_fnmae = $user_profile["first_name"];
        $user_lnmae = $user_profile["last_name"];
        $user_lcity = $user_profile["location"]['name'];
```

All the other fields work, but I can't get the current city/country of the user. Any idea where is the problem?

I changed this:

```
        $user_lcity = $user_profile["location"]['name'];
```

to this:

```
        $user_lcity = $user_profile["location"];
```

But still nothing changes.

Comment: Check if user has given permissions to city or if user has entered location

Comment: Yeah the user gives permission to the current city. He has entered and it's also public not private

Comment: try to `var_dump/var_export $user_profile`

Answer (score 1):

add `user_location` to scope

`public_profile` does not give you the location

check these. you can try graph api explorer and experiment there

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2

Answer (score -2):

```
var_dump($user_profile);//look for location in the dumped data

1)If location array is not set then no data will be there, because user might not set his location in fb profile

2)You need to set permission in your app to access location.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
```

Comment: 2) is not correct. Permissions have to be given upon OAuth process